# CSS dropdown menu just isn't working in IE 6 7 or 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have been wracking my head over this all day, and have been all over every forum I could think of looking for a solution... to no avail... please help.

I have a pretty simple website I'm working on, with a very basic dropdown menu.

It works and looks great in Firefox and in Safari... but the drop down just doesn't show up in Internet Explorer... not on any version I can find.

Here is a temporary link: [website](http://cs4.sunyocc.edu/~c.l.sayers/html/index1.html)

hover seems to be working because the link change color but the drop down fails

this is essentially a template which will be used to make the whole website later... for now I just want to get this menu working.

Also: ie seems to be putting a weird border around the logo... anybody know whats up with that?

Comment: I assume you mean the Projects link. Works for me in IE 7, 8, and 9. To get rid of the border, add a CSS rule : img { border: 0; }

Comment: @Craig M The projects drop down does not work for me in IE.

Comment: It is working on my IE as well. And border can easily be removed by CSS `{border:0;}` as told by Craig M

Comment: I just tried it in IE Tester instead of IE 9 with the 7 and 8 engines. Now I'm seeing the bad behavior too.

Comment: Could it be an opacity issue. IE is known to have issues with opacity.  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

Comment: Yea IE Tester is a great tool but I have found it is not always accurate.

Comment: Btw, just looked at your CSS. Arial is spelled with an A, not an E.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the border on the logo use this in the stylesheet:

```
a img {
border-style: none;
}
```

I tried a few things and the hover event is not working with the selectors you used:

```
#menu ul li:hover ul
```

I got it to file with this:

```
#menu ul a:hover
```

But then you can't access the UL element to show it... I think you will need Javascript to fix this in IE (at least IE6).

Comment: You'd think a huge corporation like Microfail could do a bit better than a bunch of hackers making stuff for free (FF, for example) wouldn't you? Also, +1 for effort in getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

IE6 simply doesn't support `:hover` on other elements than links. Take a look at the `sfHover` function from the [*Son of Suckerfish Dropdowns*](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) article by [HTML Dog](http://www.htmldog.com/). The function is a JavaScript alternative for IE6. I suggest you read the full article.

```
sfHover = function() {
    var sfEls = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < sfEls.length; i++) {
        sfEls[i].onmouseover = function() {
            this.className += ' sfhover';
        }
        sfEls[i].onmouseout = function() {
            this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp(' sfhover\\b'), '');
        }
    }
}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload', sfHover);
```

And for the border around the image, simply add:

```
img { border:0 }
```

Comment: Thank to the quick responses from everyone! You've been an incredible help.

My first thought also was that it would be a z-index issue so I already set the dropdown above everything else (z-index: 90;)

The problem seems to be being caused by opacity in IE. I removed the opacity filter for ie from the css and now its working fine.

The only problem is now is that I think it looks a lot better with opacity on the menu... if anybody has a solution for this I'd be glad to hear it.

thanks again!!